# What is the use of creating separate file to assign the DataContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am going through the code for SocialGoal Application that is available on GitHub (https://github.com/MarlabsInc/SocialGoal) to try and understand MVC5.

When going through the Datalayer (Social.Data.Infrastructure), the project (https://github.com/MarlabsInc/SocialGoal/tree/master/source/SocialGoal.Data/Infrastructure) uses a Separate file called DatabaseFactory.cs. It's purpose is only to create the DataContext and dispose it off.

Are there any benefits other than separation of concerns for creating a separate file like DatabaseFactory.cs just to initialize the datacontext rather than creating the datacontext inside the UnitofWork like explained in here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application for UnitOfWork Pattern. Below is sample Code used in asp.net mvc tutorial for unit of work.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
    private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
    private GenericRepository<Course> courseRepository;
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: It's mostly for SOC.I think that way its more readable.